# CATIA - CGRContainer From .CATPart

Tags: visual-c++, cad, catia, caa

I Need to read details inside the CGR container for a CATIA V5 R18 Part File.
Is it possible to read CGR details for a Part file.

`CATCGRContainer *GetCGRContainer()` function is available under `CATICGRDocument` interface.

```
CATDocument *iDoc = NULL;
CATBaseUnknown *oApplCont = NULL;

HRESULT hr = CATGetApplicativecontainer(oApplCont,iDoc,IID_CATIContainer,"CGRCont");
```

This got Suceeded but from this Applcont if we query for CATICGRDocument it fails.

How to query for CATICGRDocument interface ?

How can I read those details usng CATIA v5 R18 CAA .

Answer (score 0):

the CATICGRDocument is non-public interface.

Comment: Is there any other way to retrieve CGR container data's?

Comment: You want to tetrieve the triangles, strips, or something from Part document? Then you need to access representation in CATIVisu. In other way, you can tessellate the CATBodies directly.

Comment: How to access the representation in CATIVisu? I tried tessellating CATBodies,But it din't work for complex Part files.